# Xamarin Forms - Android App Crashes on Physical device

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am building an app on Xamarin Forms Framework and my app crashes when installing on a physical android device.

It gets fixed when I clear storage and run it again, then my app wont crash and runs good,
But every time i reinstall my app it first crashes.
Another weird thing is Release Built and Debug Built run well on the visual studio debugger.

I am working on trying to fix it all day but no success tried to cancel Optimize my Code, tried to disable link but nothing.

Edit: I use a Mac so I tried to move my project to my Windows PC and released the app to my physical device and it works well, maybe its a Visual Studio Mac Bug?

Comment: what's the crash you are getting?

Comment: Just a crash without report or even to show my first screen

Comment: I think it is a time for you now to implement some crash analytics framework in-app like AppCenter Crashes.. Without any more details, we can't say which piece of the libraries are crashing... Or atleast put some logging from the code that would log any unhandled exceptions in app/global level

Comment: Another question - Is it crashing every time when you "re-launch" the app until you clear the storage? Or is it just crashing for the very first time when you launch and then not !